# Python - Find the correct link within a post with a wildcard

Tags: python, hyperlink, wildcard, forum

i try to extract a link out of a forum with the following python code. The post contains a lot of html links, and i try to find a special one:

```
<a href="https://site.html" target="_blank" class="externalLink" rel="nofollow">Daily news <img src="https://site.html/pic.png" class="bbCodeImage LbImage" alt="[​IMG]" data-url="https://site.html/pic.png"></a>
```

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import defs
import re

def find_link(soup ,date, section, URL):
    #Find the right post
    section = soup.find('li', {"data-author":"Ghostwriter"})
    #Search the link inside the post
    link = section.find(string=" Daily news ")
    #Mark the whole html section
    section_new = str(link.find_parents('a'))
    #get the link
    link_new = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", section_new).group("url")
```

The problem ist now, that sometimes there is no space before or after "Daily news" and than my code fails:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parents'`

How can i make my code more flexible, for example with some wildcards. For example:

`link = section.find(string="*Daily news*")`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `re.compile` as an argument to `string`. This should allow you create a regex that matches the strings you are looking for. More information about python regex can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks! That works for me:
link = section.find(text=re.compile('Daily news'))

Answer (score 0):

try using tags.get to return a string then you should should be able to use str.statswith to do exactly what you want.